# Multiple AJAX requests in jQuery to get same type of information from multiple pages

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having problem to optimize this function which collects JSON data from API on multiple pages. There is no chance to get list of all on that API. So i need to send request to each page (it can be from 0 to ∞) and when i am getting response - just put everything in one object. This function works, but i need to optimize it to go trough each page and make request until i am getting information back. Thanks for help:)

```
$.getJSON('link.json&page=1', function(data) {

  $.getJSON('link.json&page=2', function(data2) {

    $.getJSON('link.json&page=3', function(data3) {

     var newObj = data.events.concat(data2.events).concat(data3.events);
     jsondata.render(newObj);      

    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
        var newObj = data.events.concat(data2.events);
        jsondata.render(newObj);        

        //alert("3 page Not Found");
    });    


  }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
      jsondata.render(data.events);

      //alert("2 page Not Found");
  });    

}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
  //alert("1 page Not Found");
});
```

Comment: " make request until i am getting information back" you mean they will mostly return nothing, but then once you get some data back that will be the last request? BTW the obvious thing to do is here to avoid the nested blocks of code is to build something recursive.

Comment: The limit on each "&page={count}" is 20 entries. So if i am having 15 entries, script is sending request to page=1, getting information, then sending request to page=2, getting nothing and just finishing with one request. And so on...

Comment: ok so it's the opposite, you want to stop when there's no longer any data. That's really the opposite of what you wrote in the question.

Comment: It should be like that then: "I am having problem to optimize this function which collects JSON data from API on multiple pages. There is no chance to get list of all on that API. So i need to send request to each page (it can be from 0 to ∞) UNTILL i am getting response AND THEN just put everything in one object. This function works, but i need to optimize it to go trough each page and make request until i am getting information back. Thanks for help:)"

Comment: "UNTILL i am getting response" implies you're not getting a response in the earlier requests, and so when you do finally get one, you want to stop. Perhaps it's just the language barrier. Instead you should say "until I am **not** getting a response"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not the best solution here but I would like to give one example here, it might help you to move further:

```
var allData = []; // In here we are storing data

function getJSON(page) {
    $.getJSON('link.json&page=' + page, function(data) {
        if (data.events.length > 0) { // Not an empty array
            allData.push(data);       // Push received data to array
            getJSON(++page);          // Recursive          
        } else {
            console.log('Ok, we are done here');
        }
    });
}

getJSON(1);
```

With this recursive function you're invoking itself as long as the response from the server is positive. After each successful request, at least in this case, you're storing the response to an array (but can be changed to something else).

**However**, there could be a few problems here. For example, it does something after 3 seconds but you can't be sure if it's enough for retrieve all the info from server.

Comment: " it does something after 3 seconds"...so why not just log inside the getJson callback, then it's reliable? Anyway, as per OP's question and comments, the callback needs to check whether there are any items in the array, and if not, stop making more requests

Comment: True, that could work. I wanted to warn that this code has some drawbacks.

Comment: That's a good idea, I was just suggesting an obvious way to avoid the drawbacks. Also if you implement the suggested change to check the length of the returned `data.events` (I assume it'll be an array by the sounds of it), then you can have an upvote, because that'll pretty much solve the problem as I understand it.

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood. I tried to improve my answer.

Comment: This seems to work, but how to merge all object into one now?

Comment: @SimonasFalkauskas everything is already in `allData`. If that's not what you want, you'll have to give a clearer definition of what your "one object" should look like

Comment: @SimonasFalkauskas It's technically one object/array with multiple elements. I might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I want to render data from allData as one object. Before i used that:
var newObj = data.events.concat(data2.events).concat(data3.events);
     jsondata.render(newObj);

Comment: @SimonasFalkauskas Do you mean you want one flat array instead of an array of arrays? Right now you have got one array (not object), but its indexes are themselves arrays. Please be clear what you mean _exactly_ by "one object", as requested already. BTW the output of your example code `var newObj = data.events.concat(data2.events).concat(data3.events); jsondata.render(newObj);` is _not_ an object, it's an array.

Comment: Yes, one flat array.

Answer (score 1):

Got everything to work myself. It's for TicketCo API when using jQuery http://apidoc.ticketco.no/#!/events/findEvents

```
var allData = []; // In here we are storing data

function getJSON(page) {
    $.getJSON('urll.json&page=' + page, function(data) {
        if (data.events.length > 0) {   // Not an empty array             
            allData.push(data.events);  // Push received data to array
            getJSON(++page);            // Recursive          
        } else {
            var flatArray = [].concat.apply([], allData); // Flatten list of all arrangements
            console.log(flatArray); // Flat results

            // Do stuff ...
        }
    });
}

getJSON(1);
```